# Как использовать usb-клавиатуру и мышь под Windows/Mac в ОС Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, клавиатура, мышь, совместимость

Купил набор клавиатура-мышь Qumo Paragon k15/m21 с USB и датчиком. Предназначены они для Windows и MacOS. Есть ли возможность использовать их на Linux(Ubuntu 20.04)? В Гугле ничего не смог найти. Система не видит их вообще.

Comment: для начала надо хотя бы lsusb посмотреть до и после подключения, также можно посмотреть вывод dmesg сразу после подключения. А там будет видно. может просто включить забыли?

Comment: Добавьте параметры ядра `debug loglevel=KERN_DEBUG printk.devkmsg=on` и  `dmesg` в студию.

Comment: @DiD там большой вывод, тут не поместится. В какую сторону смотреть? Через Гугл докс: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CAPk1uSq0gP7o3FXAe9kfoCWWFoGhSVF4kIK_XTEIj4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @KoVadim всё подключил, ноут их просто не видит. LSUSB До:
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

После:
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Без изменений

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov, под вопросом есть кнопочка [edit]. длинные простынки можно вывешивать на свой любимый pastebin-сервис (их много; примера ради: https://dpaste.com/). Lля этого в репах большинства дистрибутивов есть скриптик `pastebinit`/`wgetpaste`. Если при подключении адаптера в `lsusb` ничего не появляется, то есть вероятность, что адаптер мёртвый...

Comment: да, если в lsusb нет вывода, значит либо устройство мертво (что я и писал - может включить его или аккумуляторы проверить. Кстати, на клавиатуре, если потыкать CapsLock, должна лампочка загореться, если она есть), либо usb хаб ушло в нирвану.  Кстати, по логу видно наличие мышки, а по выводу lsusb ее нет. Странненько

Comment: @KoVadim usb на ноуте нормально работает, проверял с других устройств, сама мышка загорается, клава тоже лампочку включает, но ничего не работает - курсор стоит и буквы не печатаются, как будто мёртвая. По ходу, возвращать придётся

Comment: попробуйте на компе с windows. Может там что то не то.

Comment: А что вы логи то не включили? dmesg пустой же

Comment: И как бы точно у вас эти usb-порты работают?

Comment: @DiD порты точно работают, я телефона два втыкал в них, Линукс видел их, а потом этим же проводом и мышь, и клаву подключал - никакой реакции.

Comment: @DiD Ну я вот сделал всё, как вы сказали, прописал настройки и распечатал в терминале. Может, упустил что?

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov `[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-56-generic root=UUID=d1372424-c7d0-43b3-98ab-e6a08594b33f ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7` нету тут `debug loglevel=KERN_DEBUG printk.devkmsg=on`